# want to use image file with treeNode / PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, tree

I noticed from the [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeIcons.jsf) I can assign the expandedIcon and collapsedIcon values but I want to assign folder open and folder closed image files. Is it possible to do this and could you give me an example based on the sample below (which just displays a caret as it currently stands)

```
  <p:treeNode expandedIcon="fo.png" collapsedIcon="fc.png">
       <h:outputText value="#{node}" ></h:outputText>  
  </p:treeNode>
```

Thanks in advance

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

A debt of gratitude to [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/) (again) and [kianworknotes](http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/01/how-to-change-icon-for-primefaces-tree.html)
where I was able to piece together a quick solution to this issue.

It seems then for the tree the CSS needs to be overwritten in order to change the icons. 
In this particular case I made a test by putting a style in the `<head>` which was

```
<style>
  .folder-open {
  background: url('fo.png')!important;
  height 16px;
  width 16px;
  }

  .folder-closed {
  background: url('fc.png')!important;
  height 16px;
  width 16px;
  }
</style>
```

Followed by a slight change to my tree declaration:

```
    <p:treeNode expandedIcon="folder-open" collapsedIcon="folder-closed">
```

And thats works perfectly.